# google drive / php request for resumable upload

Tags: php, request, google-drive-api

How I can send this request in php? 
https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resumable

```
POST /upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: your_auth_token
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Upload-Content-Length: 2000000

{
  "title": "My File"
}
```

Comment: Google `PHP cURL Post Request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at php curl. you can make requests with it and change the headers from the request as you like.

**php docs**

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

**tutorial to start with**

http://coderscult.com/php-curl-tutorial-and-example/

however **google drive** has an excellent **api** so why not using that?

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

Comment: how to make such request with php client library? with Google_Http_Request ? what should I put in $url?